# I want to start parsing a text file at the first empty line

Tags: python

I want to start parsing a text file at the first empty line of a text file .The first few lines of each text file have URL's that I don't want in my search and each file has a slightly different length header. Each file has a empty line between the header and the body of text, so I would like to start my regex search after the empty line

I know how to find the empty lines but can't figure out how to get their index.

```
myfile = open(mydir,'r')
for line in myfile:
    if line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
        print 'Found it'
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: I want to skip the fist block in each file and only parse the body of text.

Comment: So why do you need the index? Your question should be "How do I skip the first block in each file" And the answer is... well you've already posted it in your question.

Comment: My logic is probably bad here but when I hit the first empty line with if line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
Then I can only do something with the empty line . What I want to do is Process the rest of the file from this point on

Comment: There are already many answers here that you should be able to use. Which of them have you tried and why don't they work for you? What error do you get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just step through the file ignoring everything until you find the empty line. Then process the rest.

```
myfile = open(mydir,'r')
for line in myfile:
    if line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
        break
for line in myfile:
    #dostuff
```

Answer (score 5):

```
with open(mydir,'r') as myfile
    next(line for line in myfile if line.isspace())
    # now myfile is at the first line after the blank line
```

Answer (score 2):

> I know how to find the empty lines but can't figure out how to get their index.

You haven't said why need the index, and I don't think you do. But assuming you (or someone else reading this question) *does* actually need the index then you can use the built-in [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) function:

```
for i, line in enumerate(myfile):
    if line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
        print 'Found it!', i
```

Note that if you want a *line number* instead of an *index* then you would normally want to start at 1 rather than 0. To do that, change the first line to this:

```
for i, line in enumerate(myfile, 1):
```

Comment: Perhaps `enumerate(myfile, 1)` to start counting lines starting with 1 would be a better option here?  (since most people start with 1 when referring to line numbers)

Comment: @Levon: Good idea. Updated answer. Not sure that this answer will help the OP though, I suspect he doesn't need the indexes or line numbers at all to solve his problem.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just start with your regex where you have 'Found it', and not worry about the line number?

Comment: Thank Must have had a mental block there for the last hour. That will do nicely. Doh!

Answer (score 0):

```
myfile = open(mydir,'r')
for index,line in enumerate(myfile):
    if line in ['\n', '\r\n']:
        print 'Found it'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> from operator import truth
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> with open('test.z') as f:
...     gen = dropwhile(lambda x: not(x == '\n' or x == '\r\n'), f)
...     gen = islice(gen, 1, None)
...     for line in gen:
...             print(line),
```